# Android: connectivity issues in background thread after alarm when "always-on" turned off

Tags: android, polling, alarm, android-alarms

### Problem description:

In my android App, I experience connectitity issues when doing a remote HTTP
("polling") call from an AsyncTask that was started after an alarm went off.

The lookup works very well when the standard Android setting **"Enable always-on
mobile data"** (Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Mobile networks) is turned
to **"on"**.

Solution that works: alarm goes of, Android "Service" receives an alarm intent,
starts a background thread (AsyncTask). The new thread acquires a partial wake
lock, establishes the connection (polling), notifies the user and releases the
wake lock.

So far, so good. The issue is that, when **always-on** is turned **"off"**, the polling fails most of the time if
the phone was in standby for a while (> 30 min).

Since the polling thread sends a notification, I directly get feedback on the
unsuccessful polling attempt.

### Motivation:

A lot of users turn of "always-on" to reduce battery drain. So, it's likely
that app users run into issues. I want to handle or prevent the "errors" that users will face.

### Solution attempts:

I have experimented a lot without any major break-throughs:

- multiple retries and intermediate sleeps to give the phone some time to establish the connection
- http parameters (timeouts, etc.)
- different HttpClient (Apache)

### Questions:

- What **excactly** does the setting "always-on" mean and what do developers have to regard?
- I am wondering if it is **generally** possible to implement an **alarm-based polling mechanism** that is able to establish a data connection even if "always-on" is
  turned "off".
- Are there any **alternative solutions** (no C2DM possible)?

### Update:

It seems that not all Android devices have the "always-on" setting. It seems to be device or, more likely, provider-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to implement a live communications protocol, and are attempting to do so with short-lived polling, this may illuminate the issue with a similar experience:

We have had a similar requirement with our app, and have noticed a few things:

1. Not every network even has the "Enable always-on mobile data" preference.  I am on Verizon with DroidX and this option isn't in the menu.  Data IS always on.
2. Contrary to what you might think, sockets are NOT killed when the phone goes into the sleeping state, even if you don't hold a partial wake lock.  Your app does stop receiving broadcast events when the phone goes to sleep (e.g. connectivity change events), so you cannot rely on the Android OS to tell you when you temporarily dropped your data connection.  Rather than doing alarm polling, consider long polling whereby you send an HTTP request with Keep-Alive, and hold the connection open indefinitely until you get a response.
3. Blocking Socket read operations will not throw an IOException, EOFException, or otherwise when you drop your signal, so you need to have a separate thread periodically check the state of the network.  The easiest way to do this is to use the NetworkInterface class and build something like this:

.

```
private OnCheckNetworkConnectivity networkConnectivityCallback = new OnCheckNetworkConnectivity() {
        String ipAddress;

        public boolean isConnected() {
            String newIpAddress = getLocalIpAddress();
            if(newIpAddress != null) {
            if(ipAddress == null) {
                ipAddress = newIpAddress;
                return true;
            }
            if(!newIpAddress.equals(ipAddress)) {
                ipAddress = newIpAddress;
                return false;
            }

            // still the same IP address, we should still have the same connection
            return true;
            }

            ipAddress = null;
            return false;
        }

        public String getLocalIpAddress() {
            try {
                for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                    NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                    for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                        InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                        if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                            return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
            return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

Comment: at 2.) I am not excactly getting your point.
a.) From my point of view, it would be ok that the socket is not dropped when the phone
goes into standby. The important thing is that (possibly way) later, the connection can
be established again. What is the problem with the not dropped socket? What
happens if the app tries to use the socket that was not dropped?
b.) Is "long-polling" really a practical approach. Consider the case where the
alarm is registered to go off in one week?

Comment: at 3.) One addition to my question: I do get exceptions (UnknownHostException) - so I think blocking is not
the issue here. From what I've experienced, the BLOCKING-Timeout works pretty well and a "SocketTimeoutException" is thrown.

Comment: I may have read too much into your question.  When you said you wanted an "alarm-based polling mechanism", I thought you were trying to  implement a live communications protocol (e.g. IM) through fast-failing polling triggered by alarms every so often.  I originally assumed that live sockets would get killed when the phone went to sleep unless you held a wake lock (which is why I explained otherwise in (2)).  (3) was designed to be an alternative to this short polling strategy using simple Comet programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AlarmManager, it should wake the device.

I wonder if you are attempting to make the connection too quickly after the phone is awakened, before it has a chance to secure a connection.

Consider:

Checking for a connection in the AlarmManager receiver.  If no connection is present, then:

Before returning from the AlarmManager receiver, start a separate thread.  In the thread:

1. Acquire a wake lock
2. Register a broadcast receiver for CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
3. Wait a reasonable amount of time for a successful connection (indicated by the broadcast receiver event).
4. If the time expires, release the wake lock and stop the thread and the phone will go back to sleep.

Try to make your connection only after receiving an event from the CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcast receiver.

Comment: @(1) I acquire a partial wake lock (in the async task), @(2) good idea. Though, for the "wake up on alarm and poll server"-situation this is not suitable since I the device would suspend immediately. I want the connection "right now". What I did is implementing busy waiting (using Thread.sleep). This makes sense here since I assume that the network will be turned on and the connection will be established as soon as my HTTP-request goes out. I actually tried to connect/sleep up to a minute - without success. So this is a general issue with "always-on" turned off. What do you think?

Comment: I think that the phone will go back to sleep as soon as you return from the Broadcast Receiver unless you have acquired a partial wake lock in that seperate thread that you started.  The idea is to allow that thread to wait for a reasonable amount of time to receive a CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcast event, and THEN try to connect.  If you try to connect and then wait, I would not be surprised to see it fail.

Comment: I have edited the answer, hopefully it is a little bit more clear.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. Two things: 1.) I do aquire a partial wake lock in the new thread. 2.) Interesting idea to register for the CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE-Event. Though, what I do is basically the same besides that I actively wait: try to connect -> sleep 10 sec -> try to connect -> sleep -> ... until I have a connection or the timeout is reached. Do you think this makes a difference? I believe not.

Comment: Are you doing the connect -> sleep 10 sec -> connect -> sleep -> ... process in the AlarmManager receiver itself?  Are you releasing the wake lock after the last attempt?  By "sleep" do you mean Thread.sleep() in this case?

Comment: No, I am not doing the sleep/connect-cycle in the alarm receiver directly. I guess this would not be allowed, either. The Alarm Receiver starts a service that in turn starts a background thread. The new background thread is doing the work. Again, the polling mechanism work very well - if "always-on" is turned on. Of course I am releasing the wake lock (in a finally block). Sleep = Thread.sleep, yes.